# How to create a range slider with multiple bubbles on it using react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I want to show a percentage number above the slider as below picture but I don't want any jQuery or another js libraries to work with. I have some blocks, what should I add to the blocks I wrote. How to achieve the slider as in the expected output?

[image: Expected output]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.middle {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

/* .slider-container .bar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 7px;
  borer-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
} */

.slider-container .slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #1D2A78;
}

.slider-container .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color:#1D2A78;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <span class="bar"><span class="fill"></span></span>
    <input type="range" id="slider" class="slider" min=0 max=100 value=50>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a div with flexbox layour (space between will help you) - inside that div add your 4 small bubbles (divs), (border radius: 50% - for circling divs).

remember to make the z-index above your input.

btw its not a react question - its more a css one.